# format datetime in big query select FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E*S','0001-01-01')

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to make the date in the below particular format in big query, but somehow it is truncating leading zero's automatically. How to get the output as is.

Query used:

```
select  FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E*S','0001-01-01')
```

output: 1-01-01 00:00:00

Desired output: 0001-01-01 00:00:00

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$E4Y` for the year:

```
select FORMAT_DATETIME('%E4Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E*S', '0001-01-01')
```

`'%Y'` uses only as many characters as needed for the year.  `'%E4Y'` always uses 4 characters.